# Parceljs to compile css inside src instead of dist

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, parceljs

I am working on a html project which is going to be integrated php. I have created a structure of js, scss, fonts, images and list of .html files inside src folder. But when run the index.html it is actually rendering from dist folder which is very complicated. I want the strucutre to remain same. So other developer can use it accordingly. only change I need is extra folder for css so the path for images is taken relatively.

Parcel bundle everything inside dist folder making it more dirty. I do not want bundles I need straight strucutre as my working directory. Is it even possible ?

my src folder structure.

- scss
- fonts
- js
- images
- index.html

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "parcel serve src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html —no-minify"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git url....."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "...."
  },
  "staticFiles": {
    "staticPath": ["src"],
    "staticOutDir" : ["public"]
  },
  "homepage": "....,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "lodash.escaperegexp": "^4.1.2",
    "parcel-plugin-static-files-copy": "^2.6.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^6.3.5"
  }
}
```

I need exactly same structure in dist folder as well. I have also used `parcel-plugin-static-files-copy` npm package. Which just copy the folder from src to dist but doesnt change the path in style.css also dist folder behaviour of copying all files in root doesnt change. Please help.

Comment: If you don't want bundles, why do you use parcel?

Comment: What other do you suggest ?  Gulp is kind of depciated and doesnt work well with node 18.  I just want to work on html part and hand the final version to the integration team. for that I dont need bundler. I just want ease of work with scss and live refresh.

Comment: If i dont care about strucutre https://medium.com/hceverything/parcel-js-moving-static-resources-to-a-separate-folder-aef63a038cbd this article helped alot. Still those paths are relative to root.

Comment: If you only want live refresh you don't need a bundler. All you need is a file watcher that refreshes the browser when something changes. You can install `live server` in VS Code, or use it in the command line: https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Comment: What about sass/*** to css compile.

Comment: Sass has a tool to convert directly to css, it’s described here: https://sass-lang.com/guide

Comment: I switched back to gulp. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the answer to the question but actually a alternate solution of I want to achieve.

I swtiched back to gulp fixing all errors. If anybody looking for same here is the code for `package.json` and gulpfile.js

package.json

```
{
  "name": "gulpexapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Example app using Gulp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.29.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.62.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3"
  }
}
```

`gulpfile.js`

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
// const sass = require('sass');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// var spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith');
/*
  -- TOP LEVEL FUNCTIONS 
  gulp.task - Define tasks
  gulp.src - Point to files to use
  gulp.dest - Points to folder to output
  gulp.watch - Watch files and folders for changes
*/

// Logs Message
gulp.task('message',  gulp.series(async function() {
  return console.log('Gulp is running...');
}));

// Copy All HTML files
gulp.task('copyHtml',  gulp.series(async function() {
  gulp.src('src/*.html')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());

}));
gulp.task('copyFonts',  gulp.series(async function() {
  gulp.src('src/fonts/*')
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());

}));
// Optimize Images
gulp.task('imageMin', () =>
    gulp.src('src/images/**/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
);

// Minify JS
// gulp.task('minify',  gulp.series(async function() {
//   gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
//       .pipe(uglify())
//       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
// });

// Compile Sass
gulp.task('sass',  gulp.series(async function() {
  gulp.src('src/scss/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass({
    includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/']
  }))
      .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
      // .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}));

// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts',  gulp.series( async function() {
  gulp.src('src/js/*.js')
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
      // .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
}));

// gulp.task('sprite', function () {
//   var spriteData = gulp.src('images/home/spr/*.png')
//       .pipe(spritesmith({
//           imgName: '../images/home/sprite.png',
//           cssName: '../sass/_sprite.scss' // <<-- just need to change this line
//       }));
//   spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest('images'));
//   spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest('sass'));
// });






gulp.task('watch',  gulp.series(function(){
  gulp.watch('src/js/*.js', gulp.series("scripts"));
  gulp.watch('src/images/*', gulp.series("imageMin"));
  gulp.watch('src/scss/*.scss',gulp.series("sass"));
  gulp.watch('src/*.html', gulp.series("copyHtml"));
  gulp.watch('src/fonts/*', gulp.series("copyFonts"));
})
);

gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass' , function() {
  browserSync.init({
      server: {
      baseDir: '/Users/santoshshah/projects/amlhtml2.0/dist',
        debugInfo: false            
      }
  });
}));
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('serve','watch','message', 'copyHtml','copyFonts', 'imageMin', 'sass', 'scripts')));
```

Note the last line of gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('serve','watch','message', 'copyHtml','copyFonts', 'imageMin', 'sass', 'scripts')));
```

In terminal we just need to run `gulp` and it will automatically run this task `default` which has series of task that will run from right to left direction starting from script and end with serve.